# Ubuntu server - HANDSHAKE_FAILURE. How to correctly set up the certificate?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to establish a connection between our server (Ubuntu, SSL certificate) and our partner (communication via AS2). When the partner is trying to connect to our server, he gets the error message **HANDSHAKE_FAILURE**.

As I have very little experience with certificates, I think the problem might be here. What I have done is that I have generated the certificate like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 365
```

and then I sent these files to our partner. He was (probably "obviously") unable to successfully establish the connection with our server.

What have I done wrong - or possibly, what am I missing yet? Do I need to register the certificates somehow or? I've tried to google the problem, but unfortunately don't have a solution to make it work.

Comment: to me looks like a problem with encryption.. try to use another one. A simple one..

Comment: Never send the `server.key` file to the remote party. That's your private key.

Answer (score 0):

openssl looks good!
`key` **AND** `crt` must be configured at your server site. `crt` must be configured at client/partner site. Common Name (CN) in `crt` must match your hostname (DNS) and must be used in the URL at the partner site.